Converting las to pnts for Cesium
I try to convert .las file to .pnts with tileset.json to be able to load it to Cesium viewer.
I convert las using py3dtiles. But despite different conversion methods I get my point cloud placed somewhere in the black space and it's a mirror image.
I used point cloud from this governament site https://opendata.geoportal.gov.pl/NumDaneWys/DanePomiaroweLAZ/70707/70707_845999_N-34-139-A-c-1-1-3-3.laz. When I load this file into QGIS, it shows that the files doesn't have assigned CRS. I know that it is EPSG:2180, so I tried a few py3dtiles conversions:

one wihout any crs specified: py3dtiles convert 70707_845999_N-34-139-A-c-1-1-3-3.las --out tileset_none_in_out
I assigned crs to this las file by pdal assign projection tool in QGIS and then converted it with: py3dtiles convert 70707_845999_N-34-139-A-c-1-1-3-3.las --out tileset_2180_in_out
again used las with crs and specified crs in py3dtiles command: py3dtiles convert 70707_845999_N-34-139-A-c-1-1-3-3_2180.las --out tileset_2180_in2180_out2180 --srs_out 2180 --srs_in 2180

But despite all these method finally I got this: (I load it in Cesium viewer in Oracle Spatial Studio).

I also used Cesium ion account to upload and convert this las file in My Assests tab and then downloaded resulting tileset. Cesium website converted it correctly:

I was uploading a file to Cesium services, but I have to convert other las files that shouldn't be published anywhere besides my organization. So my question is if am I using py3dtiles library wrong and what I have to change? Or maybe someone knows betters tools for converting .las to .pnts?

las2las in the lastools will do this.  -opts: output as PTS (plain text lidar data)

I've read documentation and help listing at https://liblas.org/utilities/las2las.html but I don;t see a -opts flag. Moreover I need a .pnts (wiht .json combining them all), not .pnt format to use it in Cesium. Could you help me with the right las2las command to use?

I've found a solution!
autra writes that output 3d tiles must be in EPSG:497 as it's a Cesium scene CRS https://github.com/Oslandia/py3dtiles/issues/66#issuecomment-576203520
But specifying --srs_out 4978 when I used point cloud in 2178 crs as an input wasn't enough. My .las files are in EPSG:2178. First I reprojected files to 4978 using Reproject tool from Point cloud data management in QGIS and then I used command py3dtiles convert my_cloud.las --out my_cloud and it worked. No --srs_out specification was needed.
